flaskapp.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
I'm working on deploying a flask application with gunicorn and nginx on ubuntu. I have set up nginx to start on boot using systemd and desire to do the same for my flask application. I get this error when I run sudo systemctl status flaskapp.
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/flaskapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-05-14 02:59:47 EAT; 10min ago
    Process: 6707 ExecStart=/home/user_name/Documents/PYTHON/flaskapp/flaskapp_venv/bin/gunicorn -w 9 run:app (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 6707 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Cam 14 02:59:47 flask-server systemd[1]: Started flaskapp.
Cam 14 02:59:47 flask-server systemd[6707]: flaskapp.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Cam 14 02:59:47 flask-server systemd[6707]: flaskapp.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/user_name/Documents/PYTHON/flaskapp/flaskapp_venv/bin/g>
Cam 14 02:59:47 flask-server systemd[1]: flaskapp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Cam 14 02:59:47 flask-server systemd[1]: flaskapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I have gunicorn installed in my virtual environment and it exists in the path specified in the unit file for the flask app. This is the unit file for the flask application.
[Unit]
Description=flaskapp
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user_name
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user_name/Documents/PYTHON/flaskapp
Environment="PATH=/home/user_name/Documents/PYTHON/flaskapp/flaskapp_venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/user_name/Documents/PYTHON/flaskapp/flaskapp_venv/bin/gunicorn -w 9 run:app
StartLimitBurst=100
StartLimitInterval=3
#Restart=on-failure


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


I've checked online sources but I'm not sure what's missing. Any help will be highly appreciated.

This has nothing to do with NGINX, it has everything to do with a problem in your underlying Flask application.  Since your flask app can't start (the error is self explanatory, whatever you're passing to the Start command doesn't exist for it to execute), this isn't nginx related
